# How to organize desktop icons in Disco Dingo

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, desktop-icons

The "Organize Desktop by Name" option no longer appears in the contextual menu in GNOME desktop (xorg if it matters) on Ubuntu 19.04.

**How does one organize desktop icons?**

Comment: Best comment I can make: swtitch to another Ubuntu. Budgie has desktop icons for instance.

Comment: @Rinzwind As you probably already know, I like Unity desktop. I like the speed of 16.04 over 18.04. I'll just sit on the fence until 20.04 comes out and then decide which side is greener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point it's not possible.

Ubuntu 19.04 comes with gnome shell extension: "desktop icons". In previous versions of Ubuntu desktop icons was provided by nautilus, but new version of nautilus (3.32) lost desktop icons functionality.

Unfortunately looks like extension's author decided not to implement any sorting/rearranging features: https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/ShellExtensions/desktop-icons/issues/98

Comment: Hopefully desktop icons reappear by the time version 20.04 comes out next year.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix They have! but NO re-arrange option from the desktop :(

Comment: @Rinzwind `iconic` lets you rearrange icons plus more options than most people dream of. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can hack around:

1. Create a copy of all files on desktop to another directory
2. Delete all files on desktop (that have been safely the copied)
3. Move the copies back to desktop

Note: if you just move all files to a different directory then back it "remembers" their previous location which is pretty annoying. Yet new instances of files are inserted in a way that's intuitive (to me at least).

Obviously this method is suboptimal because I've noticed that in 19.04 any file operations through nautilus are now painfully slow, particularly involving the desktop (note that my hardware is less than a year old and using SSDs, so it's not that). Have large monitors though, my instinct is that it could be those.

And while I'm complaining I do *not* think it's cool that my desktop changes when I show/hide hidden system files (files beginning is ".", toggled using Ctrl-h). Is that behaviour that *anyone wants*? On their desktop?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is with hide/unhide but I wrote an answer that is easier than your current hack.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [iconic](https://github.com/WinEunuuchs2Unix/iconic) that sorts desktop icons by name:

[image: iconic main menu.png]

In addition to sorting by name you can sort:

- oldest icons first
- newest icons first
- alphabetical ignoring "Link to" prefix
- manually reposition any icon in sort order

Additional benefits:

- evenly space icons
- move icons from primary display to one of two additional displays
- preview changes before applying them
- fix bug where icons disappear when a "hole" is below monitor (caused by some multiple monitor configurations of mixed resolutions)

Comment: Is this supposed to work with Ubuntu 19.04 (i.e. GNOME 3) as the question asks?

Comment: @pomsky It sorts the icons on the desktop as the question asks. It doesn't enable desktop icons which I thought the question was originally about a long time ago. At the time I thought you had to install `nemo` to enable desktop icons. I was using Unity desktop when testing 19.04 and icons were working for me.

Comment: Yeah, but the issue is desktop icon handling is fundamentally different on Ubuntu 19.04 and later (i.e. recent versions of GNOME 3). Unlike other DEs, icons are handled by a shell extension (instead of a file manager) *by default*. Perhaps better to add a caveat that this solution was tested on Unity.

Comment: @pomsky I've also read folks installed `nemo` to get desktop icons in 19.04. Then they flipped a switch to make `nautilus` the default file manager again but I haven't tested this.