# Desktop icons missing after upgrade to 1904 and also right click menu on Desktop is limited to 3 items!

Tags: icons, gnome-shell, 19.04

After upgrade from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04 without any problems now on my desktop icons are missing. I can't copy any thing to desktop! I can't create any new item on it because when I right click on my desktop it only has 3 items for settings and background. I can access to my files in desktop folder in nautilus. How can I solve this?
[image]

Comment: See this answer, you need an extension: https://askubuntu.com/a/1138753/480481

Comment: your link is about desktop ordering and organizing problem. my problem is that I cant add anything on my desktop!

Comment: I **never** said  they are the same. **As the linked answer mentions**, on Ubuntu 19.04 Nautilus no longer handles desktop icons, there is an extension for that (should be installed by default). Looks like something's wrong with the extension in your case. Please [edit] your question and the output of the following command: `apt policy gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`.

Comment: I already have this extension installed. I even have nemo installed as well. Still can't copy files to the desktop or execute any .desktop files